# delete on join not working as expected oracle

Tags: oracle, join, sql-delete

I am having a hard time getting my delete to work. I need to delete based on two columns in this case where the row exists in a source table.

I have 113843 rows in the table. My delete statement is:

```
delete from process.designer_mm_px_current_state 
where exists (select 1 from process.designer_mm_px_current_state dc
join
process.mm_px_current_state c
on dc.soid = c.soid and dc.state_id = c.state_id)
```

This reports 113843 rows deleted. But I have inserted a new row that is only in dc, so I should have one row at the end. Also:

```
select count(1) from process.designer_mm_px_current_state dc
join
process.mm_px_current_state c
on dc.soid = c.soid and dc.state_id = c.state_id
```

returns 113842 rows. Just as I expected. What am I missing? I am working in an oracle system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no reference between your inner and outer query.   Try this instead.   Dc is now your outer reference.

```
delete from process.designer_mm_px_current_state dc
where exists (select 1 from
process.mm_px_current_state c
Where dc.soid = c.soid and dc.state_id = c.state_id)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! So, the inner query is going to return true for every row in the outer query as long as the inner query returns at least one row, i.e. it exists... Is that what I did wrong?

Comment: U got it now...nice